# Spider Identification (UK)

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I found this spider (~10 mm body length) indoors on a wall (South-East England) and I was wondering what species it was.

[image]

My first guess is *false black widow*, but I can't be sure.

I'd be grateful if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's Steatoda, probably nobilis, the False Widow.  The white band curving around the front of the abdomen is a good Steatoda diagnostic, and the light-colored abdominal pattern is pretty variable in this species - only hints of it here, but the pointy front end and the bits of a skeletal 'shield' pattern are there.
The spider is pretty harmless, although it is supposed to sometimes give a bite that's like a very mild Widow bite.  Not at all dangerous, but a little more potent than the usual harmless spider bite.

Below are a couple of pictures of nobilis, showing a range of markings:

[image]

[image]

Here is a citation describing the effects of S. nobilis bites that's not a fear-mongering tabloid story:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320623444_Envenomation_by_the_noble_false_widow_spider_Steatoda_nobilis_Thorell_1875_-_five_new_cases_of_steatodism_from_Ireland_and_Great_Britain

The images were taken from a random survey of Steatoda nobilis images from the internet, as a broad selection was desired.  However, this note (below) discusses some of the features I mention, along with photographs that support my comments.

https://cisr.ucr.edu/european_spider.html